# time integration property of fourier transform

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

I am having some trouble with some Fourier transform,

Suppose that $F(\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of $f(x)$, i.e. where

$$F(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-i\omega x}\,dx.$$

What is $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{F(\omega-a)}{i\omega}e^{i\omega x}\,d\omega ?$$
I was thinking of using the time integration property, since $i\omega$ appears at the denominator, but I am not sure how to start it.

Answer (score 1):

One possible derivation:

Note that
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{F(\omega-a)}{i\omega}e^{i\omega x}\,d\omega  = 
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{F(\omega-a)}{i\omega}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}e^{i\omega x}\,d\omega\\
= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(\omega-a)e^{i\omega x}d\omega
= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(\omega')e^{i(\omega'+a) x}d\omega'\\
= e^{iax} \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(\omega')e^{i\omega' x}d\omega'
= e^{-iax}f(x)
$$
So we must have
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{F(\omega-a)}{i\omega}e^{i\omega x}\,d\omega =
\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-iat}f(t)\,dt + C
$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But how did u derive your step?

Comment: So what I'm really saying with all this is that you can find the answer by applying the frequency-shift property, and then applying the time integration property to the result.  Does that answer your question?  I'm not sure what step you're talking about, since there are several.

Comment: Sorry, I meant your last step, where u have x in the limits of the integral.

Comment: So, I should have an integration constant at the end there.  I thought we should have $C = 0$ at first, but now I'm not so sure.

Comment: We'd have 
$$
C = \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{F(\omega-a)}{i\omega}e^{i\omega x}\,d\omega
$$
which I suppose you could argue is zero for a nice enough function?  Really not sure though.

Comment: Hmm... Let me think